# Symfony2 error on render controller with relation OneToOne on same table

Tags: symfony, controller, rendering, render, one-to-one

I have a problem to get a object from a controller called by the render controller method.

This is my Entity with the self OneToOne relation :

```
class Family
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Family")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brother_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $brother;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $label;
}
```

This is my action:

```
/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $brothers = $em->getRepository('FifaAdminBundle:Family')->findAll();

    return array(
        'brothers' => $brothers,
    );
}
```

My view

```
{% for brother in brothers %}
    {{ brother.id }} - {{ brother.label }}
    <hr />
    {% render controller('AdminBundle:Test:show', {'brother': brother}) %}
    <hr />
    {{ render(controller('AdminBundle:Test:show', { 'brother': brother })) }}
    <hr />
{% endfor %}
```

My other controller

```
public function showAction($brother)
{
    if (is_object($brother))
    {
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('OK');
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump($brother);
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('KO'); 
    }
}
```

The first element isgood.
But if it has a brother_id, this brother in not load by the showAction.

It gives me this:

```
array(1) { ["__isInitialized__"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `@ParamConverter` annotation in your case.

Your controller would go as follow:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Admin\Bundle\Entity\Family;

/**
 * @Route("/show/{id}")
 * @ParamConverter("family", class="AdminBundle:Family")
 */
public function showAction(Family $brother)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

And the view:

```
{% for brother in brothers %}
    {{ brother.id }} - {{ brother.label }}
    <hr />
    {{ render(controller('AdminBundle:Test:show', { 'brother': brother.id })) }}
    <hr />
{% endfor %}
```

Note that if no `Family` object is found, a 404 Response is generated. So you don't need to check if `$brother` is an object or not in your controller.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you cheesemacfly

Indeed, it's work with the @ParamConverter

But it is wird because if I remove the OneToOne relation, it works without @ParamConverter